# Returning a dynamic field in a RESTful manner

Tags: web-services, rest, http, jersey

I have a business object that has a secret that needs to change every time the object is requested and viewed. Whenever this secret changes, the new secret needs to be saved to a datastore. Currently, I have it set up where a `GET` for the object changes the secret and persists the change, but this clearly violates REST design. How do I ensure this secret is unique per render while avoiding changing any data through `GET`?

I was thinkin I'd have the user `POST` something like `object/{id}/secret` which would in turn change the secret when called. However, this leads to the question of how douy return this new secret if, in general, you try to avoid return payloads for `POST`?

I don't want to return a `Location` header that points to this new secret because this would mean that I could theoretically `GET` that url multiple times to get the same secret, but this is not allowed for my business object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a violation of REST principles if the state of the resource changes with every `GET` request. Think about something like a 'timestamp of last access' which is part of the resource, not set by the client, and changes with every access. The 'secret' is very similar.

So I would use `GET` and have the server change the secret.

Request 1:

```
GET /objects/1234
```

Response 1:

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": 1234
  "title": "foo",
  "secret": "abcd"
}
```

Request 2:

```
GET /objects/1234
```

Response 2:

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": 1234
  "title": "foo",
  "secret": "efgh"
}
```